# I'm trying to get the pixel colour for a C4 image, how do I access the image colour matrix? c4framework

Tags: c4

In the discussion of the colour colorMatrix:bias it reads :

> This filter performs a matrix multiplication, as follows, to transform the color vector:
>
> s.r = dot(s, redVector) s.g = dot(s, greenVector) s.b = dot(s, blueVector) s.a = dot(s, alphaVector) s = s + bias

Is there any way to gain access to the data values for the various colour vectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The discussion you're referring to, in the C4 documentation, refers to the process that a filter uses for calculating a matrix multiplication. This is actually just a description of what the filter does to the colors in the image when it gets applied.

In fact, what's happening under the hood is that the `colorMatrix:` method sets up a `CIFilter` called `CIColorMatrix` and applies this to a `C4Image`. Unfortunately the source code for the `CIColorMatrix` filter isn't provided by Apple.

So, a longwinded answer to your question is:

You can't access color components for pixels in a `C4Image` through the `CIColorMatrix` filter. But, the `C4Image` class has a property called `CGImage` (e.g. `yourC4Image.CGImage`) which you can use to get pixel data.

A good, simple technique can be found [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/448758/1218605)

EDIT:
I got obsessed last night with this question, and added these two methods to the C4Image class:

Method for loading pixel data:

```
-(void)loadPixelData {
    NSUInteger width = CGImageGetWidth(self.CGImage);
    NSUInteger height = CGImageGetHeight(self.CGImage);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    bytesPerPixel = 4;
    bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width;
    rawData = malloc(height * bytesPerRow);

    NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData, width, height, bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), self.CGImage);
    CGContextRelease(context);
}
```

And a method for accessing pixel color:

```
-(UIColor *)colorAt:(CGPoint)point {
    if(rawData == nil) {
        [self loadPixelData];
    }
    NSUInteger byteIndex = bytesPerPixel * point.x + bytesPerRow * point.y;
    CGFloat r, g, b, a;
    r = rawData[byteIndex];
    g = rawData[byteIndex + 1];
    b = rawData[byteIndex + 2];
    a = rawData[byteIndex + 3];

    return [UIColor colorWithRed:RGBToFloat(r) green:RGBToFloat(g) blue:RGBToFloat(b) alpha:RGBToFloat(a)];
}
```

That's how I would apply the techniques from the other post I mentioned.